# Quickly determining whether given lattice is a distributive lattice from a given Hasse diagram

Tags: group-theory, relations, order-theory, lattice-orders

I came across following fact while reading online:

> If a given Hasse diagram contains following structures, then it wont be the distributive lattice
>   [image]

I am unsure if the above fact is correct and if it is, then whether are these exhaustive substructures required to be contained in given Hasse diagram in order for a lattice not a distributive lattice. In other words, if the fact is true, then can there be a non distributive lattice with Hasse diagram not containing any of these structures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Wikipedia's article on [distributive lattices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_lattice#Characteristic_properties):
"A lattice is distributive if and only if none of its sublattices is isomorphic to $M_3$ or $N_5$."

Yes, it is correct. It is a complete characterization of distributive lattices.
The proof is not difficult, but it is rather elaborated.

Comment: ohh the diagram was a copy paste from the wikipedia itself (which I too copied from my source )!!!

Comment: Ok, so maybe you overlooked the content of the page? Anyway, if you're interest, and in case you don't have access to much bibliography, a reference book on Universal Algebra which has a good introduction to Lattice Theory is [A Course in Universal Algebra](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~snburris/htdocs/UALG/univ-algebra2012.pdf), where you can find the proof of this characterization (Theorems I.3.5 and I.3.6). Good luck! :)

Comment: [JB Nation](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~jb/)'s "Notes on Lattice Theory" is another excellent (and freely available) resource.